# Help with jQuery's .live() method

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a function that dynamically creates links for a photo gallery. The function also produces a larger image as a background image of a div when and thumbnail is clicked on. What I want to do is have a third event, where if the user clicks the enlarged image in the div, the jQuery Fancybox loads an even bigger version of the image being displayed in the div. The problem is that the link for the anchor tag I'm using is created dynamically, and I know that Fancybox parses the HTML when the DOM is ready...unfortunately my function changes the DOM by appending the anchor tag for the full sized image. The help I need is using the Fancybox's options to specify the href attribute for the plugin. I'm sorry that was so long-winded...here's the code.

jQuery:

```
function gallery(picid, picnum){
var ext = 'jpg';
var fullSize = 'imgs/'+picid+'_full.'+ext;
$('#photolarge').css("background", 'url(imgs/'+picid+'_large.'+ext+') no-repeat');
$('#photolarge a').attr(
    {   href: fullSize
        //rel: 'lightbox',  
    }
    );

$("#lightboxlink").click(function(){
    $('#lightboxlink').fancybox({
        'autoDimensions' : false,
        'width' : 'auto',
        'height' : 'auto',
        'href' : fullSize
        });


    });

return false;
}
```

HTML Snippet

```
<div id="photolarge">
   <a id="lightboxlink" href="#"></a>
</div>
        <div id="phototable">
            <ul id="photorow1">
                <li><a onclick="gallery('bigsun',1)"><img id="sun" src="imgs/bigsun.jpg" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#photolarge {
width: 590px;
height: 400px;
margin-left: 7px;
border: 2px solid;
background: none;}

#phototable {
width: 590px;
height: 300px;
border: 2px solid;
margin: 10px 0 0 7px;}

#phototable img {
cursor: pointer;}

#phototable ul {
list-style: none;
display: inline;}

#phototable li {
padding-left: 10px;}

#lightboxlink {
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi christian, can u post a link to ur page ?

Comment: @Avinash The page hasn't gone live yet and I'm in between web hosts right now. Is there something else I can do?

Comment: Is it possible for u to post the code on http://jsbin.com | http://jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: The links to the images that the javascript builds for me wouldn't work correctly on there...though that is a useful resource!!

I don't think I could load the Fancybox plugin remotely for jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works,this is just fancy box bit though,the rest of your code seems fine

```
$("#lightboxlink").live('click', function(){

    $.fancybox({
        'autoDimensions'  : false,
        'width'           : 'auto',
        'height'          : 'auto',
        'href'            : $(this).attr('href')
    });
    return false;
});
```